# How to store/retrieve an uploaded file using GridFS, MongoDB and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I've searched through APIs for this but I can't seem to find what I need. Looking at the mongo driver API, it looks like I need to use a GridFSBucket and the stream methods. However, all the examples shown pass a filename in order to start the upload process. My question is how to do I process, store and retrieve a file that has been uploaded through an 'input type="file' form? Preferably, I want to store the buffer or typed array so I can then easily display it upon retrieval, but if that's not possible I can probably work around that.

The goal of my app is to upload PDF files, and render them in a canvas using PDFJS.Here's the code I have so far:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> Test File </title>
</head>
<body>
   <input type ="file" id = "pdf_file" value = "Upload" />
   <input type ="submit" id = "submit" value = "Submit" />
   <div id="canvases" style ="position:relative;">
        <canvas id="layer" style = "z-index: 2;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px; top:0px; background-color: #00ff00; opacity:0.1"></canvas>
        <canvas id ="pdf-canvas" style=" z-index: 1; position:absolute;
        left:0px; top:0px; border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

  </div>
  <script src="test_annotate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test_annotate.js

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {

  var file =document.getElementById("pdf_file").files[0];

  console.log("new file!");
  //Step 2: Read the file using file reader
  var fileReader = new FileReader();


        fileReader.onload = function() {

              //Step 4:turn array buffer into typed array
          var typedarray = new Uint8Array(this.result);

           //Step 5:PDFJS should be able to read this
          PDFJS.getDocument(typedarray).then(function(pdf) {

            // Fetch the first page
            var pageNumber = 1;
            pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
              console.log('Page loaded');

              var scale = 1.3;
              var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

              // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
              var canvas = document.getElementById('pdf-canvas');
              var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
              canvas.height = viewport.height;
              canvas.width = viewport.width;


              // Render PDF page into canvas context
              var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: context,
                viewport: viewport
              };
              var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
              renderTask.then(function () {
                //set the annotation canvas size to match the size of the pdf
                var canvas_container = document.getElementById('canvases');
                canvas_container.style.height = renderContext.viewport.height;
                canvas_container.style.width = renderContext.viewport.width;
                var layer = document.getElementById('layer');

                layer.height = renderContext.viewport.height;
                layer.width =  renderContext.viewport.width;

              });
            });
          });

        };

//Step 3:Read the file as ArrayBuffer
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

App.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs  = require('fs');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('frontend'))

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
//Grid = mongodb.Grid;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(err, db) {
if(err) return console.dir(err);

  var bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(db);
  /*What do I do here to store the uploaded file in test_annotate.js
  using mongoDB and GridFS??? */
});
```

Comment: i would start by storing the file locally first then stream from it.like this // streaming from gridfs
var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
  filename: 'my_file.pdf'
});

Comment: @Caspain Caldion How do I store the file locally? I've been searching for a while now but there's nothing like a FileWriter which would do the same a FileReader would. It looks like the only way to do it is to create an object URL and save that. However I need something that would happen behind the scenes without user intervention.